# Why does this python correctly output the 16 bit 2s complement?

Tags: python

Let binStr be an integer array, and number be the integer to "translate" to binary.

```
count = len(binStr) - 1
while count >= 0:
      binStr[count] = 0 if number%2 == 0 else 1
      number //= 2
      count -= 1
```

I wrote this while fiddling around and noticed it works for both signs. Why does this work for both negative and positive numbers? It should yield the same bits for negative and positive, but it actually works correctly and does not. Why?

Comment: `-3 // 2 == -2`; `3 // 2 == 1`.

Comment: You are basically copying bits one by one from ``number`` to ``binStr``.  ``number`` is stored in 2's complement form already, so obviously the result will be as well.  The whole reason why we use 2's complement (instead of any of the various other ways of representing signed numbers) is that it basically just works, regardless of the sign (or signedness) of the operands, without any special handling.

Comment: Ah, I see. 2s compliment is awfully handy.

Comment: @jasonharper: Python's integers don't have a fixed size. How is `number` stored in 2's complement form?

Comment: @Blender: Although it isn’t relevant here, Python’s integers do explicitly act like two’s complement: `-1 & n == n`.

Answer (score 0):

whoops i misread the question initially...

yeah the core issue is that floor division works differently for positive and negative numbers, as noted above by Ryan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would you mind explaining what you mean? What's being coerced? You can [edit] your answer to provide more detail. Perhaps you could give an example.